# Is it possible to solve the drag simulation equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to simulate an object's movements with air drag force through time, I need to know its coordinates' relation with time.

I've done some work, but I can't solve my equation. Here's my thought:

In the following description, all vectors (accelerations, forces, coordinates, etc) are two dimensional.

Assume $a$ is object's acceleration, $m$ is object's mass, $f_{drag}$ is the drag force and $g$ is gravitational acceleration, I have:

$$a=\frac{mg + f_{drag}}{m} = g + \frac{f_{drag}}{m}$$

I know $\left\lvert f_{drag} \right\rvert = k \left\lvert v \right\rvert ^ 2$, $k$ is a constant number, $v$ is the object's velocity, and the drag force's direction is opposite from the velocity direction, so $f_{drag}=-kv\left\lvert v \right\rvert$. Assume $p$ is the object's coordinate and $t$ is time elapsed, then $v = \frac{dp}{dt}$ and $a = \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{d^2p}{dt^2}$, we have

$$\frac{d^2p}{dt^2} = g - \frac{k \frac{dp}{dt} \left\lvert \frac{dp}{dt} \right\rvert}{m}$$

But I don't know how to solve it or if it is possible to be solved. If I know at time $0$, the object's coordinates is $p_0$ and its velocity is $v_0$, how can I get its coordinates at time $t$?

If I can't get the object's accurate coordinates, can I approach its accurate coordinates as close as possible in an efficient way?

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Thanks, this helps. Can you make it as an answer so I can finish this question?

Comment: I did just that @EFanZh. Excellent simulations !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for example detailed in [Parker's paper](http://users.df.uba.ar/sgil/physics_paper_doc/papers_phys/mechan/air0.pdf) for the $2$D case (and $3$D restricted to the vertical plane of the movement) and this [one](http://www.physics.udel.edu/~szalewic/teach/419/cm08ln_quad-drag.pdf) for the simpler integrable $1$D case. Note that $g$ should be replaced by $-g$ if your axis is oriented up.
For other numerical solutions ($2$D case) you may look at this simple [method](http://www2.southeastern.edu/Academics/Faculty/dnorwood/classes/PLAB223/Numerical.pdf) or the more sophisticated [Runge-Kutta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) (computations get more complicated but more accurate) and other methods exposed [here](http://www.worldacademicunion.com/journal/SSCI/sscivol05no01paper03.pdf) .